# Core Data and many Entity

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I'm newbie and I must save "Ranking" and "Level" of user.
I create file `Ranking.xcdatamodel` for save "Ranking"
with entity name Ranking (property is Rank, Name) I can save and show it.

But when I create entity Level (property is CurrentLevel) my program is crash and show this message:

> Unresolved error Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100
>   UserInfo=0x60044b0 "Operation could
>   not be completed. (Cocoa error
>   134100.)", {
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 248;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Users = ;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>           );
>           NSStoreType = SQLite;
>           NSStoreUUID = "41225AD0-B508-4AA7-A5E2-15D6990FF5E7";
>           "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>       };
>       reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one
>   used to create the store";
>   }

I don't know how to save "Level"
please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have saved data based on one model, then changed that model and tried to re-open the same file.

You need to delete the saved file which will be (I think, from top of my head) in the ~/user/Library/ApplciationSupport/YourAppName directory, unless you are developing a document based application.

Then re-run your application and re-enter and re-save your data.

Comment: During development, it is fine to delete the data store and repopulate it. In production, this obviously not viable. Have a read over the Model Versioning Programming Guide (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Note that the question is from an iPhone tag so the database is stored in the simulator.  Reset the simulator or delete the app from the simulator.